Issue Running 2d-space.cc Example in NS-3 with THz Module Installed
I'm currently working on 6G technology and I'm trying to utilize the THz module in NS-3. I've followed the steps provided in the documentation to create a new file named 2d-space.cc in contrib/thz/examples, and I've also updated the CMake file accordingly. However, when I attempt to run the code, I encounter an error.
I've tried clearing the build and rebuilding the project, but the issue persists. It's worth mentioning that I come from a Python development background and I'm not very familiar with CMake.
Here are the specifics:
NS-3 version: 3.41
Location of the new file: contrib/thz/examples/2d-space.cc
Error message received when trying to run: abdullah@abdullah:~/MyData/6g/ns-3-dev$ ./ns3 run 2d-space Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/abdullah/MyData/6g/ns-3-dev/./ns3", line 1917, in main() File "/home/abdullah/MyData/6g/ns-3-dev/./ns3", line 1864, in main raise Exception("Couldn't find the specified program: %s" % target_to_run) Exception: Couldn't find the specified program: 2d-space abdullah@abdullah:~/MyData/6g/ns-3-dev$ ns3 --version

I would greatly appreciate any insights into what might be going wrong and how I can resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!
after creating the new file i again built ns3 and also ran ./test.py file but it gave me no error but when i try to run the newly created file it gave me issue.
